# Resolve two Async Code Samples

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I need to return a `Dictionary<string, byte[]>` from a list of Urls.

I have one code sample that is executing properly asynchronously, but only returns a `List<byte[]>`, and another which seems to be properly casting the object, but is throwing threading errors.

```
//Seems to assign to the output type correctly, but doesn't execute properly
async Task<Dictionary<string, byte[]>> ReturnFileData(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    Dictionary<Uri, Task<byte[]>> dictionary;

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        dictionary = urls.Select(url => new Uri(url)).ToDictionary(
            uri => uri, client.DownloadDataTaskAsync);
        await Task.WhenAll(dictionary.Values);
    }

    return dictionary.ToDictionary(pair => Path.GetFileName(pair.Key.ToString()), pair => pair.Value.Result);
}

//Executes properly, but isn't returning the right output type
async Task<List<byte[]>> ReturnFileData2(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    Dictionary<Uri, Task<byte[]>> dictionary;
    var tasks = urls.Select(uri => new WebClient().DownloadDataTaskAsync(uri));
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return results.Select(result => result).ToList();
}
```

How do I take `ReturnFileData2()` and fix it to cast the filename of the `Uri` alongside the returned `byte[]` in the output?

Answer (score 3):

You should stick with ReturnFileData but rework it to use a separate client for each URL:

```
async Task<Dictionary<string, byte[]>> ReturnFileData(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    Dictionary<Uri, Task<byte[]>> dictionary = urls
        .Select(url => new Uri(url))
        .ToDictionary(uri => uri, GetTheDataAsync);

    await Task.WhenAll(dictionary.Values);

    return dictionary
        .ToDictionary(
            pair => Path.GetFileName(pair.Key.ToString()),
            pair => pair.Value.Result);
}

async Task<byte[]> GetTheDataAsync(Uri uri)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        return await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use the newer `HttpClient`:

```
async Task<Dictionary<string, byte[]>> ReturnFileDataAsync(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
  Dictionary<string, Task<byte[]>> dictionary;

  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    dictionary = urls.ToDictionary(uri => uri, client.GetByteArrayAsync);
    await Task.WhenAll(dictionary.Values);
  }

  return dictionary.ToDictionary(pair => Path.GetFileName(pair.Key), pair => pair.Value.Result);
}
```

Though I would probably write it like this, avoiding the intermediate dictionary:

```
async Task<Dictionary<string, byte[]>> ReturnFileDataAsync(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(async url => new
    {
      Key = Path.GetFileName(url), 
      Value = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url),
    }));
    return results.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
  }
}
```